# Can C# Interactive show timing information?

Tags: c#, read-eval-print-loop, c#-interactive

In *F# Interactive*, I can get timing information by using the `#time` directive:

```
> #time;;

--> Timing now on

> [1..1000_000] |> List.rev |> List.head;;
Real: 00:00:00.159, CPU: 00:00:00.156, GC gen0: 6, gen1: 3, gen2: 0
val it : int = 1000000
```

Likewise, in *GHCi*, I can get the same information with `:set +s`:

```
Prelude> :set +s
Prelude> head $ reverse [1..1000000]
1000000
(0.20 secs, 96,304,704 bytes)
```

Notice that in both examples, the REPL reports the time it took to evaluate the expression.

Is a similar option available for *C# Interactive*, and if so, how do I enable it?

Comment: It is not the kind of question anybody ever answers with "no!"  Given the likelihood that somebody might get ticked-off at the missing feature, adds it and submits the pull request.  Could be you.  But otherwise might be a while, the github depository is not very active.

Comment: Given what Hans just said, I'm going to say "no!". Well, I'm pretty sure it's not possible, at least the [docs](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window) don't suggest it. I personally prefer doing my interactive stuff in LinqPad.